# Backup local working tree including unpushed commits, branches and stashes

Tags: git, backup

I want to backup my home directory now and then but local repositories are a bit problematic because of the size.

Some repositories are huge not because of the working tree but because of git objects. For example the selenium project (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) has 1.6 GiB in .git/objects. But all this data is also available on the remote and for my backup I can assume it is not removed from there.

First I thought I can just remove the .git and later do something like

```
$ git init
$ git remote add <previous remote>
$ git checkout -b <previous branch>
$ git branch --track ...
$ git reset --soft <remote>/<branch>
```

But a) thats also a pain if you have to do it for 20+ repos and b) you loose stashes and unpushed commits/branches.

Is there no command to just remove all refs that are already available on the remote and restore them from the remote if it gets necessary? Something like a `git hibernate` and a `git restore` command?

Comment: No, I don't think, because that's not how git is supposed to work. Maybe take the habit to do shallow clones. Have a look at creating git bundles but you will have to write a complex script to achieve something approaching to what you want...

Comment: What @Philippe said, plus the newfangled "partial clone" stuff. Ideally, with partial clones, you should be able to "ream out" a repository based on some presumably-very-trusted promisor remote, but currently there's nothing to do that.